# Can I set the source of an img element to be the path to a file in my local server?

Tags: python, html, image, flask, filesystems

I am trying to get the user to upload a file. This uploaded file is then stored on my flask file system and returns the [url](/questions/tagged/url)or path to the file so it can be displayed.
However I am getting a 404 error when I try to set the [src](/questions/tagged/src)attribute of the [img](/questions/tagged/img) tag to the returned [url](/questions/tagged/url).

**FILE SYSTEM**

- root

  - app.py
  - templates

    - index.html
  - uploads

**SERVER SIDE (PYTHON-FLASK)**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["UPLOADS"] = "uploads"

@app.route("/save", methods=["POST"])
def save():
    image = request.files.get("image")
    file_name = secure_filename(image.filename)
    if not file_name: // ensures function does not return an empty string
        file_name = image.filename

    file_path = os.path.join(app.config["UPLOADS"], file_name)

    image.save(file_path)

    return {"path": file_path}
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="img" width="100px" alt="Image" src=""/>
<form action = "/submit" method = "post">
    <input type = "file" id="uploaded-img" name="image" /></p>
    <button type = "submit" id="upload"></button>
</form>
<script>
    document.querySelector('#upload').addEventListener('click', async function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let file = document.getElementById("uploaded-img").files[0]; 
        fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("image", file, file.name);

        let res = await fetch("save",{
           method: "post",
           body: fd
        });
        let response = await res.json(); // returns {path: *path to file*}

        let path = response.path;
        document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("src", path); // gives a 404 not found error
    });
</script>
```

The file is successfully saved in the uploads folder but I am unable to access it from the client end.
And if I try to refer the image from the absolute path,
`return {"path": os.path.abspath(file_path)}` , will not work because 'browser not allowed to load local resource'

Comment: can you access the file from the browser with the path that is in response json? You might need to alter image path

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.
The same is true for `<input>`

Answer (score 0):

1. If the `response.path` is the absolute path to the uploaded image on the server. To make this work, you need to convert the absolute path to a URL that the client can access. Assuming that your Flask app is running at `http://localhost:5000`, you could modify the `imageUrl` line like this:

```
let imageUrl = "http://localhost:5000/" + path;
```

This will construct a URL that points to the image served by your Flask app.

2. Ensure you've configured Flask to serve the static files properly. Add the following line to your app.py to set up the static file serving:

```
app.static_folder = 'static'
```

Then also replace 'uploads' folder with 'static'.

3. In your HTML form, you've set the action attribute to `"/submit"`, but your Flask app has a route defined for `"/save"`. The form submission might be leading to a 404 error if Flask can't find a matching route. So, update your HTML form action attribute to match the Flask route:

```
<form action="/save" method="post">
```

*Final Codes*

SERVER SIDE (PYTHON-FLASK):

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["STATIC"] = "static"
app.static_folder = "static"


@app.route("/")
def save():

    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/save", methods=["POST"])
def myy():
    image = request.files.get("image")
    file_name = secure_filename(image.filename)
    if not file_name:
        # ensures function does not return an empty string
        file_name = image.filename

    file_path = os.path.join(app.config["STATIC"], file_name)

    image.save(file_path)

    return {"path": file_path}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    

<img id="img" width="100px" alt="Image" src=""/>
<form action = "/save" method = "post">
 <input type = "file" id="uploaded-img" name="image" /></p>
       <button type = "submit" id="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
<script>
    document.querySelector('#upload').addEventListener('click', async function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let file = document.getElementById("uploaded-img").files[0]; 
        fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("image", file, file.name);

        let res = await fetch("save",{
           method: "post",
           body: fd
        });
        let response = await res.json(); // returns {path: path to file}

        let path = response.path;
        console.log(path);
        // Update the following line to provide a correct URL for the image
        let imageUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/" + path; // Modify the hostname and port if needed

        document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("src", imageUrl);

        // document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("src", path); // gives a 404 not found error
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]